# Why don't disassembled code use register DIL instead of register AL?

Tags: clang, x86-64, disassembly

C Code:

```
void charTypes(char a)
{
    return ;
}

void intType(int a)
{
    return ;
}
```

Assembly:

```
0000000000000000 <charTypes>:
   0:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
   4:   55                      push   rbp
   5:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   8:   89 f8                   mov    eax,edi
   a:   88 45 fc                mov    BYTE PTR [rbp-0x4],al
   d:   90                      nop
   e:   5d                      pop    rbp
   f:   c3                      ret    

0000000000000010 <intType>:
  10:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
  14:   55                      push   rbp
  15:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  18:   89 7d fc                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
  1b:   90                      nop
  1c:   5d                      pop    rbp
  1d:   c3                      ret
```

In case of `char` parameter, Why do we need to assign `edi` to `eax`?
What prevents this?

```
DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],dil
```

Comment: *Why do we need to assign edi to eax?*  We don't, but you told the compiler not to optimize so it didn't.  This is just some detail of compiler internals and how it represents 8-bit stuff internally.  And since you compiled without optimization, those internals end up producing some actual wasted asm instructions.  Like I said in answering your previous question, un-optimized code is usually not interesting to look at.  Crap like this is one of the reasons for that.

Comment: @PeterCordes: What would be a best optimization level as a beginner in disassembly? I don't want to miss learning actual operation.

Comment: I'd recommend `-Og` or `-O1 -fno-inline-functions` at least, and most of the time `-O2 -fno-tree-vectorize -fno-unroll-loops`.  There isn't a way that avoids optimizing away constants and stuff, so you have to write functions that take args and return a result or modify an array or something else that can't just optimize down to `return 1234`.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) has some suggestions, and a link to Matt Godbolt's talk.  Using https://godbolt.org/ to match up source lines with asm helps a lot.

Comment: @PeterCordes: With these optimizations I found out that the function preamble is missing. So are the optimized code really executable by computer?

Comment: Yeah, `-fomit-frame-pointer` is enabled at most optimization levels.  Those instructions in each function that set up RBP as a frame pointer and then tear down the stack frame aren't special or necessary, RBP is just a normal register.  There's no magic here.  [x86\_64 : is stack frame pointer almost useless?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31417784).  If you compile a whole program and single-step the asm with a debugger (like gdb `layout reg`), you'll see the instructions that really execute.